# Hypergeometric Series Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For the hypergeometric series $\sum_1^\infty $ $(a)_n (b)_n \over(c)_n n!$, I am looking for help proving that the series converges for $a+b-c<0$. I can understand divergence for different parameters, but am looking for help in understanding convergence with these parameters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $(a)_n$ mean?

Comment: $(a)_n = a(a+1)(a+2)...(a+n-1)$

Comment: Have you tried D'Alambert ratio test?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee  See [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)

Comment: @MBYagbasan Yes- but that gives a value of 1: inconclusive.

Comment: See p.7 https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/kyle.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I assume $c$ is not a negative integer, so you don't have trouble with $0$ denominators.  If $t_n$ is the $n$'th term we have

$$ \dfrac{t_{n+1}}{t_n} = \dfrac{(n+a)(n+b)}{(n+c)(n+1)} = 1 + \dfrac{a+b-c-1}{n} + O(1/n^2)$$

Use [Gauss's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html).

Comment: How did you derive that last expression?

Comment: \begin{align*}
    \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}&=\frac{(\gamma + n) (1 + n)}{(\alpha + n) (\beta + n)} \\
    &=\frac{(\frac{\gamma}{n} + 1) (\frac{1}{n} + 1)}{(\frac{\alpha}{n} + 1) (\frac{\beta}{n} + 1)} \\
    &= (1+\frac{\gamma}{n})\cdot(1+\frac{1}{n})\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{\alpha}{n})}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{\beta}{n})}\\
    &= (1+\frac{\gamma}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\gamma}{n^2})\cdot(1-\frac{\alpha}{n}+\frac{\alpha^2}{n^2}+\ldots)\cdot(1-\frac{\beta}{n}+\frac{\beta^2}{n^2}+\ldots)\\
    &= 1+\frac{\omega-\alpha-\beta+1}{n}+\frac{\omega_n}{n^2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Use Raabe's Test for the hypergeometric series. In the end, derive the condition a+b-c<0, from the test's conclusion (>1, convergent ; <1, divergent)
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]